# Mapping vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

That's could be a newbie question.

There is an abstract function $ \mathbf {h(X_i,X_j)}$
what does mean

> for some function **h** mapping $$\mathbb R^q \times \mathbb R^q \to \mathbb R^p$$ where the **q** -
>   dimensional row vectors $\mathbf X_i$ and $\mathbf X_j$ are the nodal covariate vectors
>   for the *i*-th and *j*-th individuals.

What happens with vectors **X**?

Thanks for patience =)